# Populate new column based on existing column checked against regex pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a data frame in Pandas as below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Firstname':['Vishal', 'Nishal', 'Indira', 'Jagdish', 'Tamnna'], 'Actual Age':[25,33,58,58,30]})

  Firstname  Actual Age
0    Vishal          25 
1   Nishant          33
2    Indira          58
3   Jagdish          58   
4    Tamnna          30
```

and a regex:

```
\w+ish\w*
```

What I cant seem to figure our is to provide a result as below:

```
  Firstname  Actual Age  CopyDown
0    Vishal          25    Vishal
1   Nishant          33   Nishant
2    Indira          58   Nishant
3   Jagdish          58   Jagdish
4    Tamnna          30   Jagdish
```

So basically what i want to do is look through the Firstname column, and if i can match the regex given, continue copying down that value in a new column until the next match is found, and basically keep doing that until you get to the end.

Any ideas? Ive been stuck on this for days. Its basically a copydown feature i want to implement which might be useful in denormalised datasets. (using dates as stuff)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it. First identify whether there is a match. Then `groupby` using `cumsum` trick. Finally, populate each sub group using the first value.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

# your data
# =============================
print(df)


  Firstname  Actual Age
0    Vishal          25
1   Nishant          33
2    Indira          58
3   Jagdish          58
4    Tamnna          30

# processing
# =============================
pattern = re.compile(r'\w+ish\w*')

df['matched'] = [(pattern.match(x) is not None) for x in df.Firstname.values]
df['diff_names'] = df.matched.astype(int).cumsum()


def func(group):
    group['CopyDown'] = group['Firstname'].values[0]
    return group.drop(['matched', 'diff_names'], axis=1)

df.groupby('diff_names').apply(func)


  Firstname  Actual Age CopyDown
0    Vishal          25   Vishal
1   Nishant          33  Nishant
2    Indira          58  Nishant
3   Jagdish          58  Jagdish
4    Tamnna          30  Jagdish
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `Series.str.extract("(\w+ish\w*)")` to get the matches.

Then you can use the `Series.fillna(method='ffill')` to fill the empty matches forward

This line should be enough:

```
df['CopyDown'] = df.Firstname.str.extract('(\w+ish\w*)').fillna(method='ffill')
```

Comment: Thanks, this seemed to work a charm, i had the first part when you used the extract, but never thought of the fillna method.

Comment: @VishalJethwa No problem. The `fillna` method is full of surprises and does a lot more than one thing. This makes it tricky to fully understand. Did you end up going with my solution or did you take Jianxun Li:s solution?